# Summing two lists together

Tags: python, list, sum

Observing that `[1, 2] + [3, 4]` yielded `[1, 2, 3, 4]`, I reasoned that `sum([[1, 2], [3, 4]])` should do the same, but instead I got this error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'
```

Can someone please explain this? I know I can use `itertools.chain`, but why doesn't this work?

Comment: Have you checked the [documentation for `sum`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum)?

Comment: I see "The iterable‘s items are normally numbers, and the start value is not allowed to be a string." which does not explain my problem.

Comment: @Brandon `Sums start and the items of an iterable from left to right and returns the total. start defaults to 0. start defaults to 0.`; since you cannot do `0 + [1,2]` you get the `TypeError`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> *start* defaults to 0.

[source](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum)

```
sum(..., [])
```

Comment: Yes, you're right, `sum([[1,2], [3,4]], [])` will yield [1, 2, 3, 4] as expected by question author.

Comment: Note that while `sum` *can* do this, you really shouldn't use it for this purpose. This kind of `sum` will take `O(N**2)` time because it has to keep copying the early part of the result as it concatenates the later values on to the end (it's an example of a [Schlemiel the Painter algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schlemiel_the_Painter%27s_algorithm)). `itertools.chain` (passed to `list` if you need a list object rather than an iterator) will be `O(N)`.

Comment: @Blckknght you're right for immutables (like string, which is why ''.join(string) is better, also O(N)), but in the case of a list, I don't see why it would have to copy the list, it would just extend it. See note 6 of the python 3.3 docs, section 4.6.1 (applies to py 2.7, but different section, and not as clearly explained). That being said, I have not tested.

Comment: @Schollii: While you're right in theory, that `sum(lst, [])` could use in-place addition to concatenate lists quickly, the actual implementation of `sum` doesn't do so. It always uses `__add__` rather than `__iadd__`, even if the latter is available for the given types. There's [a comment in the source code](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/e8cead08c556/Python/bltinmodule.c#l2414) that warns that this behavior shouldn't be changed because it could break backwards compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

[`sum`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum) will do following:

1. initialize `result = 0`
2. for each `element` in input list: `result += element`
3. return `result`

So 2nd step will yield such error. You trying to do `result += element`, where `result = 0` and `element = [1, 2]`. This should yield TypeError.

Comment: Thanks, Burhan Khalid, for link to documentation.

Comment: Note that the implementation of step 2 is really `result = result + element`, which has slightly different semantics than `result += element` for mutable values. `sum` will not use the `__iadd__` method even if the type has one (as `list` does), and so the overall sum may be much more expensive to compute than you would expect (`O(N**2)` rather than `O(N)`). See [this comment in the source](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/e8cead08c556/Python/bltinmodule.c#l2414).

Answer (score -1):

Sume works like this

```
    sum([[1,2], [3,4]])
```

As you can see in the documentation of sum function , sum works by adding each new element to the previously held value. In this case you are trying to add [3,4] + 1 which will lead to the error as adding list and int doesn't make sense.

Comment: This answer is wrong.  First off, `sum([1,2],[3,4])` isn't what the questioner asked about. You're passing `[3,4]` as the `start` parameter, which is probably not useful. Further, your `sum` call tries to add `[3,4] + 1`, not `[1,2] + 3` as you suggest.